# Showing all data in a datewise order grouped by dates

Tags: mysql

Currently I have 2 tables, a listing table and a logs table. With the following query I'm trying to get the listings of a product on a particular day, and it returns the right output.

```
with X as (
  select 
    l.*,
    (select status_from from logs
         where logs.refno = l.refno
           and logs.logtime >= '2021-10-01'
         order by logs.logtime limit 1) logstat
  from listings l
  where l.added_date < '2021-10-01'
)
, Y as (select X.*, ifnull(X.logstat, X.status) stat20211001 from X)
SELECT 
  status.text,
  COUNT(Y.id) AS c 
from status
left join Y on Y.stat20211001 = status.code
group by status.code, status.text;
```

This gives an output like this:

[image]

Here I've filtered the query by 1 date which in this case is 2021-10-01. Now I have 2 input forms where the user can select a from date and a to date. So I want to be able to get all the data between the date range provided. So basically if I choose a date between 2021-10-01 and 2021-10-02, it should show everything on and between that date. The output should look like:

| Date | Publish | Action | Let | Sold | Draft |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-01 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-10-02 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 2 |

Dbfiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5e0b8d484a41ac9104d0fb002e7f9a3c

I've formatted the table to show the entries in a row wise manner with the following query:

```
with X as (
select l.*,
(select status_from from logs where logs.refno = l.refno and logs.logtime >= '2021-10-01' order by logs.logtime limit 1) logstat
from listings l
where l.added_date < '2021-10-01'
)
, Y as (select X.*, ifnull(X.logstat, X.status) stat20211001 from X)
SELECT
sum(case when status.text= 'Action' and Y.id is not null then 1 else 0 end) as `Action`,
sum(case when status.text= 'Draft' and Y.id is not null then 1 else 0 end) as `Draft`,
sum(case when status.text= 'Let' and Y.id is not null then 1 else 0 end) as `Let`,
sum(case when status.text= 'Sold' and Y.id is not null then 1 else 0 end) as `Sold`,
sum(case when status.text= 'Publish' and Y.id is not null then 1 else 0 end) as `Publish`
from status
left join Y on Y.stat20211001 = status.code
```

Now I just need it to show a new dates column which shows all data on that particular date and have a new entry for each date.

Comment: You might combine what you have with https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/224182/generate-dates-between-date-ranges-in-mysql

Comment: Okay so I tried this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=819918b9abcc2822d80ff817ab38ea61 and it returns all the dates in my listings table and not between that of a date range I choose.

Comment: Indeed, that was not the kind of "combine" I had in mind.  I may have some time to look into it later in the evening.  In the mean time, you could try to understand what happens in the link I showed you.

Comment: Alright thanks will look into combining statements

Comment: There are 5 `status` columns for each date?  So, for week you would have 35 columns of counters?

Comment: Hmm no so as you can see by the table example I've provided, the dates for a day are on the left side with thier statuses next to them. So for a week, it would bring up 7 rows excluding the header and 6 columns like in the table.

Comment: Any idea on how I can achieve this?

Comment: I suppose MariaDB isn't an option?   With the connect engine they have pivot tables.

Comment: So I ran select @@version; in my database and it returned 10.4.21-MariaDB. So I think I can use pivot here

Comment: Check if you have or can install the connect engine.

Comment: Hmm so I've these engines as of now https://imgur.com/a/ubbH2Gn . Also I cannot add any new engines, since I do not have access to change the database.

Comment: @JayModi That's the task of the DBA.  Did you ask him or her?  I gave a possible answer without resorting to a pivot.  A pity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look below and at [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f9c516f6cae31ef5edb6c876f721b4d4)

```
with Y as (
  with recursive D (n, day) as (
    select 1 as n, '2021-09-25' my_date
    union
    select n+1, day + interval 1 day from D
      where day + interval 1 day < '2021-10-15'
  ) select * from D
), X as (
  select Y.day,
         l.*,
         (select status_from from logs
            where logs.refno = l.refno
              and logs.logtime >= Y.day
            order by logs.logtime
            limit 1) logstat
    from listings l, Y
    where l.added_date <= Y.day
), Z as (
  select X.day, ifnull(X.logstat,X.status) stat_day, count(*) cnt
    from X
    group by X.day, stat_day
)
select Z.day,
  sum(case when Z.stat_day = 'D' then Z.cnt else 0 end ) Draft,
  sum(case when Z.stat_day = 'A' then Z.cnt else 0 end ) Action,
  sum(case when Z.stat_day = 'Y' then Z.cnt else 0 end ) Publish,
  sum(case when Z.stat_day = 'S' then Z.cnt else 0 end ) Sold,
  sum(case when Z.stat_day = 'L' then Z.cnt else 0 end ) Let
  from Z
  group by Z.day
  order by Z.day;
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks

Comment: Please, do some testing by adding some listings and logs to see if the result table changes accordingly.  One can't be too careful.

Answer (score 0):

Start with a 3-column table

```
SELECT date, status, count(*)
    FROM ...
    GROUP BY date, status
```

Then "pivot", using the above as a derived table (that is, `FROM (SELECT...)`).

Don't bother with `WITH`, it only confuses the issue.

Comment: Could you please show the output with a dbfiddle for reference